# In wordpress how to edit footer.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog on wordpress.com ( [xxxxx].wordpress.com ) where I want to add Google Analytics in the blog page's footer. I am using the free "able" theme. I tried to find the option to edit the template's `footer.php`, but no luck yet.

I even tried to look under "appearance" menu, but nothing useful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add code Google Analytics to a widget "Text" and put widget in the footer. 
But the template not permit adding footer.

Comment: I see "Left sidebar" and "Right sidebar" in "able" theme. There is no "footer" section. So where to add that widget?

Comment: Also that widgets strip <script> tag and show the code on the page.

Comment: Choose a different theme.
Or put in the "Left sidebar" or "Right sidebar". Why must in the footer?

Comment: Unfortunately probably not work(( "Can I use Google Analytics?
No, Google Analytics cannot be used on WordPress.com blogs at this time." (http://en.support.wordpress.com/stats/)